xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unclosed token with XML Library
I am getting following error when I am trying to parse XML using Python XML library.
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unclosed token

I am using following code to parse xml string.
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
try:
   root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
   emp = root.findall(".//employees")
   .... further process with emp........
exception:
   pass

I want to continue even if there is an invalid XML string. I am passing this XML string from the dataframe column.
Can anyone suggest how we can avoid this error while parsing xml string or how do we correct the xml like lxml has some recover option while parsing xml (one thought is using lxml, correct missing xml tags by using recovery option and use Python XML library for parsing XML string, but I am not sure how we can implement this).
Please suggest how we can handle it, and really appreciate your help.

Same question here

How looks your xml file? Suggestion, correct the input file.

Fix the input file by hand. And yell at someone who gave you such broken data.


I want to continue even if there is an invalid xml string

That's not the way XML works. HTML parsers do their best to repair broken data and make sense of it. XML parsers reject bad data by design, rather than trying to guess what it's supposed to mean.
As you mention, there are tools that try to repair bad XML before you submit it to an XML parser. But really, the whole point of agreeing to exchange data in XML is that you only get the benefits if both parties use real XML and not some undefined approximation to it.
